# Change the background color of a ListViewItem on populate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

this is tearing my hair out,

I have a listview

```
<ListView Canvas.Left="1045"  Canvas.Top="667"  FontSize="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"   FontFamily="Gill Sans MT" Height="173" Name="lvContact" Width="536" SelectionChanged="lvContact_SelectionChanged">
```

In my code behind im dynamically adding an item to the list

```
public void UpdateContactList(Hashtable contactList)
{
    this.lvContact.Items.Clear();

    SortedDictionary<string,string> sortedContactList = new SortedDictionary<string,string>();


    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in contactList)
    {
        sortedContactList.Add(de.Key.ToString(), de.Value.ToString());
    }


    foreach (var de in sortedContactList)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem contactItem = new System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem();
        string contactItemString = de.Key.ToString();

        System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem text = new System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem();

        text.Content = contactItemString;
        if (de.Value == "NLN")
        {
            text.Background = Brushes.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            text.Background = Brushes.Gray;
        }
        lvContact.Items.Add(text);
    }
}
```

However the background color never changes and the list doesnt update.

Any ideas why ?
Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can't Add items to a list in ItemsSource mode, you need to change the item source.

Comment: my ListView in my xaml is of type System.Windows.Controls.ListView is this bound incorrectly ?

Comment: If you want to change the content of your listview change whatever the DataContext's 'Item' property is containing... or don't bind the itemsource and then you will be able to directly alter the list view items.

Answer (score 1):

ListViews can either be bound to an `ItemsSource`, or you can specify the `ListView.Items` manually. You cannot have both.

Your ListView definition binds your `ListView.ItemsSource`, so you cannot manually specify `ListView.Items`.

Since your `ItemsSource` is bound to a property `Items`, then I would assume you have a `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` somewhere called `Items` with the items for your ListView. To modify the ListView's Items, you should be modifying this collection.

To change the Background color based on a value, I would use a DataTrigger. This will allow you to keep your ItemsSource bindnig, and keeps your data separated from your UI.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="NLN">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTriggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```